# loader button mode

Tags: xml, flash, actionscript, slider, loader

i wrote some piece of code of image slider where i can load images from xml. everything goes fine but when i want to make loaded image button mode it goes wrong and seys:

"ReferenceError: Error #1056: Cannot create property buttonMode on flash.display.Loader."

here is a full code:

```
    import flash.display.Stage;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.net.URLLoader;
    import flash.xml.XMLDocument;
    import flash.text.TextField;
    //tween - start
    import fl.transitions.Tween;
    import fl.transitions.easing.*;
    import fl.transitions.TweenEvent;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    //tween - end
    //timer-start
    import flash.utils.Timer;
    //timer-end

        var myStage:Stage = this.stage;
        myStage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
        myStage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;

        var sliderXML:XML = new XML();
        var sliderXMLurl:String = 'sliderXML.xml';
        var sliderXMLreq:URLRequest = new URLRequest(sliderXMLurl);
        var sliderXMLloader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(sliderXMLreq);
        sliderXMLloader.addEventListener("complete",loadXML);

        var sliderNum:int = 0;
        var sliderMaxNum:int = 0;
        var LastSliderNum:int = 0;
        var strTitle:Array = [];
        var strPosterLink:Array = [];
        var strVideoLink:Array = [];
        var poster:Array = [];

        var Playing:int = 1;


    addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, fl_EnterFrameHandler);
    myStage.addEventListener(Event.RESIZE, ResizeHandler);

    var myTimer:Timer = new Timer(10000); //10 second
    myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, viewNext);
    myTimer.start();

    function fl_EnterFrameHandler(event:Event):void
    {
        var swfWidth:int = myStage.stageWidth;
        var swfHeight:int = myStage.stageHeight;
        slider_bg.width = swfWidth;
        slider_bg.height = swfHeight;
    }

    function loadXML(event:Event):void{

        sliderXML=XML(sliderXMLloader.data);
        var xmlDoc:XMLDocument = new XMLDocument();
        xmlDoc.ignoreWhite = true;
        var menuXML:XML = XML(sliderXMLloader.data);
        xmlDoc.parseXML(menuXML.toXMLString());

        //var X:int = 100;

        for each(var listItem:XML in sliderXML..listItem){

                 strTitle[sliderMaxNum] = listItem.itemTitle.toString();
                 strPosterLink[sliderMaxNum] = listItem.posterLink.toString();
                 strVideoLink[sliderMaxNum] = listItem.videoLink.toString();

                 var _temp:Loader = new Loader();
                 poster.splice(sliderMaxNum, 0, _temp);
                 poster[sliderMaxNum].load(new URLRequest(strPosterLink[sliderMaxNum]));
//i think that here must be done something
                 addChild(poster[sliderMaxNum]);
                 poster[sliderMaxNum].x = myStage.stageWidth;
                 poster[sliderMaxNum].y = 28;
                 poster[sliderMaxNum].buttonMode = true;



                 poster[sliderMaxNum].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, poster_click(sliderMaxNum));

                 sliderMaxNum = sliderMaxNum+1;
                 }
        LastSliderNum = sliderMaxNum - 1;
        //*************************************************
        var myTween:Tween = new Tween(poster[sliderNum],'x',Strong.easeOut,poster[sliderNum].x,(myStage.stageWidth - 640)/2,2,true);
        //*************************************************
    }
```

i think that here is a problem:

```
for each(var listItem:XML in sliderXML..listItem){

                 strTitle[sliderMaxNum] = listItem.itemTitle.toString();
                 strPosterLink[sliderMaxNum] = listItem.posterLink.toString();
                 strVideoLink[sliderMaxNum] = listItem.videoLink.toString();

                 var _temp:Loader = new Loader();
                 poster.splice(sliderMaxNum, 0, _temp);
                 poster[sliderMaxNum].load(new URLRequest(strPosterLink[sliderMaxNum]));
//i think that here must be done something
                 addChild(poster[sliderMaxNum]);
                 poster[sliderMaxNum].x = myStage.stageWidth;
                 poster[sliderMaxNum].y = 28;
                 poster[sliderMaxNum].buttonMode = true;



                 poster[sliderMaxNum].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, poster_click(sliderMaxNum));

                 sliderMaxNum = sliderMaxNum+1;
                 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have found the solution and did some changes so now my code looks like this:

```
             var _temp:Loader = new Loader();
             poster.splice(sliderMaxNum, 0, _temp);
             poster[sliderMaxNum].load(new URLRequest(strPosterLink[sliderMaxNum]));
         poster[sliderMaxNum].contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadedImage);


function loadedImage(event:Event):void {
   posterWidth[sliderMaxNum] = event.target.content.width;
   posterHeight[sliderMaxNum] = event.target.content.height;
   var PosterSprite:Sprite    = new Sprite();
   PosterSprite.addChild(poster[sliderMaxNum]);
   PosterSprite.buttonMode    = true;
   PosterSprite.useHandCursor = true;
   addChild(PosterSprite);
   poster[sliderMaxNum].x = myStage.stageWidth;
   poster[sliderMaxNum].y = 28;

   poster[sliderMaxNum].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, poster_click(sliderMaxNum));

   sliderMaxNum = sliderMaxNum+1;
}
```

so everythig works fine here. and great thanks all of you!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: The object that you have in your poster array is a Loader, not a Sprite. buttonMode is actually a property of the Sprite class. Loader is related to Sprite in that both of them descend from DisplayObject, but loader has some unique properties of its own and more or less lives in its own branch of the family tree.

You could do something like this. Find the line that says "poster[sliderMaxNum].buttonMode = true" and change it to say something like this:

```
Sprite(poster[sliderMaxNum].content).buttonMode = true;
```

That SHOULD give you the behavior you want. It's not entirely pretty and it's not type-safe (meaning if you add anything other than a Loader to poster, it will break) - but for your purposes it should work.

Let me know if that solves the problem, or if any part of that is confusing.

Cheers!

Comment: Weird, you're getting the same error? You can enable line numbers on runtime errors, see here: http://mykola.bilokonsky.net/2010/08/get-line-numbers-on-runtime-errors-in-flash/ That should help to narrow down the exact cause.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the Loaders inside their own Sprites:

```
             var _temp:Loader = new Loader();
             poster.splice(sliderMaxNum, 0, new Sprite());
             poster[sliderMaxNum].addChild(_temp);
             _temp.load(new URLRequest(strPosterLink[sliderMaxNum]));
             addChild(poster[sliderMaxNum]);
             poster[sliderMaxNum].x = myStage.stageWidth;
             poster[sliderMaxNum].y = 28;
             poster[sliderMaxNum].buttonMode = true;
```

Comment: Error: Error #2069: The Loader class does not implement this method.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
poster[sliderMaxNum].contentLoaderInfo.content.buttonMode = true;
```

Comment: This unfortunately won't work if the loaded content is a Bitmap -- Bitmaps do not have the buttonMode property.

Comment: TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.